Copy an EC2 EBS Snapshot into GovCloud: SnapshotCopyUnsupported.InterRegion Error
Question
I have an EC2 EBS Snapshot in a Commercial region that I need to copy into a GovCloud account.  Is it possible to do this?
Using aws ec2 copy-snapshot I get an SnapshotCopyUnsupported.InterRegion error.
What I've tried so far
Snapshot: snap-0000000000000snap
Owner Account: 1111111111
Snapshot Region: us-west-2
Target GovCloud Account: 093333333333

The Owner Account lists the Snapshot as Private, but has Target GovCloudAccount listed under Shared accounts.
From a Cloudshell in Target GovCloudAccount, I've tried using aws ec2 copy-snapshot to copy the snapshot into us-gov-west-1

[cloudshell-user@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ aws ec2 copy-snapshot \ 
--source-region us-west-2 \
--source-snapshot-id snap-0000000000000snap \
--destination-region us-gov-west-1

An error occurred (SnapshotCopyUnsupported.InterRegion) when calling the 
CopySnapshot operation:
Snapshot copy is not supported from 'us-west-2' to 'us-gov-west-1'

